# Getting distance between person and camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I want to know the distance of person form camera . i am using android motorola tablet.

i am using camera api of android -  API Level 14.

**i am using following formula:**

```
objectDistnance = ((objectheight(pixel) * focal-length(mm)) / imageheight(pixel);
```

imageHeight is height of my preview screen;
focal length i am getting from Camera api : 4.42 mm;
object height i am giving as input of person's height in mm  : 1620mm

and i want to calculate the distance of person from camera.

by using this formula i am getting wrong distance it is giving me 60mm but actually it is more then 2500mm

so please anyone help me with this
am i using correct formula ?

what should i do to get the correct distance of person from camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-of-an-object-in-a-photo) I got the following formula:

```
distance to object (mm) = focal length (mm) * real height of the object (mm) * image height (pixels)
                          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          object height (pixels) * sensor height (mm)
```

So it seems you did not include enough reference variables.

Lets asume the following:

```
Focal Length: 4,42mm
Real Height of object: 1620mm
Image Height: 2048px
Object Height: 1024px
Sensor height: 24mm

4.42mm * 1620mm * 2048px
-----------------------
1024px * 24mm
```

The Result of this would be `1193 mm`
Since I don't know all of your variables I could not recalculate your situation.

*edit*
I just checked this formula using my Samsung Galaxy S with the following values:

```
3.79mm focal length 
100mm real object height
2592px image height
1200px object height on image
4.54mm sensor height
```

I took a picture from about 200 - 250 mm away (I did not measure the exact distance). The result of this calculation is ~200mm which would fit to this test.

Comment: How u are saying sensor height is 24mm ? i couldnt get can u please explain ? with what reference Sensor height is 24mm

Comment: how object height is 1024 px ?please explain i am not able to understand.

Comment: That depends on the camera you are using. I just took a size I found on the internet of a DSLR. On Android it will be much smaller! You can get Information about the sensor size [here] (http://cameraimagesensor.com). How to get these information using the Android API I do not know

Comment: Object height is the height of the object in the taken picture. I assumed it would be 1024px height. This value must be calculated by yourself. Those values are only example values...

Comment: If object height is height of object in taken picture, then what will be Image height?

Comment: The total height of the taken picture

Comment: Thanks Zerd! It is very use full for me. Thank you so much.